# Custom Observer not triggering

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer

I have been trying to resolve this issue for 2 days but cannot seem to find the issue why the observers won't trigger. I hope some good soul out there might spot the issue and help me out on this on.

Background:
I want to write an observers which are triggered when an item is added to the cart and when the order was confirmed/checked out. The observers will ultimately update some customField in Jira and get some files into the magento database as well. But currently they should just write two files into the /tmp directory.

**etc/webapi_rest/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="jira-confirmation-update" instance="one\two\Observer\JiraConfirmationUpdate" />
    </event>
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="jira-get-attachments" instance="one\two\Observer\JiraGetAttachments" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer/JiraConfirmationUpdate.php**

```
<?php
namespace one\two\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class JiraConfirmationUpdate implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function execute(Observer $observer)
  {

  $fp = fopen('/tmp/confirm.txt', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, 'order confirmed!');
  fclose($fp);

  }
}

?>
```

**Observer/JiraGetAttachments.php**

```
<?php

namespace one\two\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class JiraGetAttachments implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function execute(Observer $observer)
  {

  $fp = fopen('/tmp/add2cart.txt', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, 'getting attachments!');
  fclose($fp);
  }
}

?>
```

just on a side note, when i run **php JiraGetAttachments.php** in the terminal i get the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/one/two/Observer/JiraConfirmationUpdate.php on line 7
```

is that the an usual behaviour?

**EDIT**
for some reason after enabling the module I can not checkout anymore, disabling the module will make it possible to checkout again...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code step by step make sure module name must be in caps

> app\code\One\Two\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'One_Two',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app\code\One\Two\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="One_Two" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app\code\One\Two\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="jira-confirmation-update" instance="One\Two\Observer\JiraConfirmationUpdate" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app\code\One\Two\Observer\JiraConfirmationUpdate.php

```
<?php
namespace One\Two\Observer;

class JiraConfirmationUpdate implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("Here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately this doesn't work for me

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: when i manually try to check out as a customer i get "Something went wrong with your request. Please try again later." If i try to checkout again i get "Current customer does not have an active cart.". It should be mentioned that I'm stuck at the last step and cannot finish the order. The "templog.log" file wasn't created so i can only guess that the observer didn't trigger

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to get magento2 Observer working can be found in the following files inside the vendor folder.

```
magentofolder\vendor\magento\module-catalog\etc\frontend\events.xml
magentofolder\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Observer
```

If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.

Comment: Thanks for the information I will take a look at those observers

Comment: @jinnn You are welcome, If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.